ASN1 corrupted data exception when converting .cer and .key files to .pfx in C#
I have a .cer file, .key and a password. I need to convert them to a .pfx file in .NET 6 but I have not a clear idea how to do it.
With the help of ChatGPT I came up with this code but it is not working as it should, I get an exception:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: ASN1 corrupted data.
   ---> System.Formats.Asn1.AsnContentException: The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '16', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '2'.

My code:
public async Task<string> ConvertToPfx(string certFilePath, string keyFilePath, string password)
{
    byte[] certData = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(certFilePath);
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certData);

    byte[] keyData = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(keyFilePath);
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(keyData, out _);  //  <-- Exception here

    var certWithPrivateKey = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);

    byte[] pfxData = certWithPrivateKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password);
    string pfxPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(certFilePath)}.pfx");
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(pfxPath, pfxData);

    return pfxPath;
}

Feel free to make the necessary changes or propose other alternatives.

This question is similar to: How can I generate a .pfx file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You probably have a key in a different format than RSAPrivateKey.  Try ImportPkcs8PrivateKey.

I already tried with ImportPkcs8PrivateKey and got the same exception. Any other ideas? Thanks for your comment @bartonjs

The gist is "what you have isn't the format of the method you're calling".  If it looks like text (-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----) then you need to call the PEM import, otherwise if it's binary gibberish then you need to know what data format it corresponds to and call the correct import.  If it's all XML-y that's yet another format.   -- The bones of the code are otherwise correct.  But no one can really help you with "what format is this?" without you posting a sample, and if it's your real private key you'll have just disclosed it to the internet.

Hi! I was able to solve it this way: rsa.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password), keyData, out _); Thanks for your comments.
